# Any difference between "He was taken down there." AND "He was taken there."?

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

**"Anyway, he got drunk and he was taken down there."** [ITV-This morning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCCCt8R69U0) (see:5:08-5:15)

**"take someone to a place"** is the usual structure in every day life. For instance **"He took me to the concert."** Is there a need for us to add **"down"** in the sentence? No.

Then why did she say **"...he was taken DOWN there?"** whereas **"...he was taken there".** would simply suffice?

Is it because the place he was taken to was very close?

Comment: In some contexts, prepositions (including, but not limited to ***up, down***) are entirely optional, and contribute little or nothing to the meaning of an utterance. If you ask *"Where's the nearest shop?"*, and you're not *obviously* on a hill, you might get either of the answers *"It's just up the road"* OR *"It's just down the road"*. There probably aren't many contexts where the imperatives *"Come up here!"* and *"Come down here!"* are interchangeable, but in almost all contexts, *either* of those could be replaced by just *"Come here!"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really any difference - it's just 'extra' information, although in this case it is somewhat unnecessary. 'Down' is obviously an adverb of *direction*, but we use 'up' and 'down' in ways other than travelling vertically. We say "going up" to mean travelling north and "going down" for traveling south (eg "*I'm going up to Scotland*" or "*I'm heading down to London*"). We also use "down" when travelling towards the centre of a town or city (hence "*downtown*") or to a place located there ("*I'm going down to the shops*").

The context of your example is someone being taken to a bar - a place that is commonly in a town/city centre or some other central commercial area - so it isn't unusual to say someone went "down" to such a place. It doesn't sound natural with "concert" because that is an *event*, not a *place*. If perhaps someone said "*he took me down to London to see a concert*" that would be fine, because the adverb is referring to the journey to the place.

Comment: Knowing which way is known as "up" or "down" can be a matter of local knowledge.

Comment: @Peter Well, obviously. If you don't know where you are, you can't possibly know where you're going.

Comment: For example in many railway systems "up" is towards the centre, even if it is physically lower.